# Is it possible to build an AngularJS App without using multiple files

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if it is possible to build an AngularJS app in a single file versus having multiple .js files.

Comment: it is, but if it is any sizable app this would become very hard to manage very quickly.

Comment: Also, this format isn't really suited for simple yes or no type questions.

Comment: *taps fingers* waiting for the 3 character "yes" answer.

Comment: Claies, would I structure it so that what would have been the mainController and app javascript files are their own scripts within the html file?

Comment: if that's how you want, sure....

Comment: [I would recommend reading John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Answer (score 0):

During developing having one file makes no sense, cause it is very hard to support such code. For production you can use special tools, so user will see only one js file. This is done for angular itself -- you can find angular source to contain plenty of files, while when you include angular in project you include just one angular-XXX.js file.

Comment: `special tools` is a pretty vague term